How to minimize & close Gtk4 Window using GtkGestureClick on GtkImage?
I am trying to minimize and close the window by clicking the GtkImage (icon). For this I use GtkGestureClick on two different GtkImage, as I have checked minimize icon is working, but my problem is, window close icon is not working properly after unminimizing the GtkWindow. This is my demo script, can anyone test it?
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
GtkWidget *window, *grid;

// window close cb function //
static void close_app_cb (GtkGesture *click,
                          int n_press,
                          gdouble x,
                          gdouble y,
                          gpointer user_data)
{
    GApplication *app=g_application_get_default();
    g_application_quit(app);
}
// window minimize cb function //
static void minimize (GtkGestureClick *gesture,
                      gint n_press,
                      gdouble x,
                      gdouble y,
                      gpointer   data)
{
      gtk_window_minimize ((GtkWindow *)window);
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_decorated ((GtkWindow *)window, FALSE);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 300, 300);

  grid = gtk_grid_new ();
  gtk_window_set_child ((GtkWindow   *)window, grid);
  gtk_grid_set_row_spacing ((GtkGrid *)grid, 15);

 /* window close icon */
  GtkWidget *c_btn = gtk_image_new_from_icon_name ("window-close-symbolic");
  gtk_image_set_icon_size (GTK_IMAGE (c_btn), GTK_ICON_SIZE_LARGE);
  gtk_grid_attach ((GtkGrid *)grid, c_btn, 1, 0, 1, 1);

  GtkGesture *gesture1;
  gesture1 = gtk_gesture_click_new ();
  g_signal_connect (gesture1, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (close_app_cb), NULL);
  gtk_widget_add_controller (c_btn, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture1));

 /* window minimize icon */
  GtkWidget *m_btn = gtk_image_new_from_icon_name ("window-minimize-symbolic");
  gtk_image_set_icon_size (GTK_IMAGE (m_btn), GTK_ICON_SIZE_LARGE);
  gtk_grid_attach ((GtkGrid *)grid, m_btn, 0, 0, 1, 1);

  GtkGesture *gesture2;
  gesture2 = gtk_gesture_click_new ();
  g_signal_connect (gesture2, "pressed", G_CALLBACK (minimize), NULL);
  gtk_widget_add_controller (m_btn, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (gesture2));

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;
  #if GLIB_CHECK_VERSION(2, 74, 0)
      app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS); 
  #else
        app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE); 
  #endif
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);
  return status;
}


I got the program to compile and execute, but to do so, I had to change the "G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS" tag to "G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE" which hints that this is actually not a GTK4 project.  You might need to check your compile and build options so that they are referencing the correct GTK version, or try the above tag change as I did.

No problem with GTK version 4.14.2. The demo script has been modified.. Thank you

For me and with Ubuntu 24.04 the script works without any problems.
